# API какой навигационной карты использовать в том или ином случае

Tags: yandex-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Я являюсь заказчиком CRM - системы по автоматизации логики и логистики доставки еды. В проекте выступаю в роли бизнес-аналитика, проект планирует решать задачи, связанные с просчетом оптимальных маршрутов, учетом километража, временем, пробками и прочее, и от сюда вытекает несколько вопросов (дело происходит в городах Украины):

- Какой сервис посоветуете для просчета максимально точного расстояния по маршруту?
- Какой сервис для выбора оптимального маршрута?
- Из какого  стоит брать учет пробок?
- Какой сервис даст максимально приближенное время в пути?
- Каким сервисом выводить навигацию курьерам в планшет и по средством чего (приложен+проброс маршрута из web или сразу в браузере)?
- Какой сервис знает больше всего адресов в городах Украины и обновляет названия вовремя?

p.s. - Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Насколько я помню, у яндекса прямым текстом в правилах использования описан запрет на мониторинг транспорта.

Comment: о мониторинге речи не идет, лишь о получении и аналитики данных